# primary key specifying two columns

Tags: mysql

I am learning about sql and saw the following:

```
create table order_items
( orderid int unsigned not null,
  isbn char(13) not null,
  quantity tinyint unsigned,

  primary key (orderid, isbn)

);
```

The line in question is: `primary key (orderid, isbn)`

How can you have two columns set as primary keys? How does this work? I understand having one column as a primary key like your social security, it's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key is one or more columns that have the following two properties:

- The values are unique.
- The columns are not null.

This simply means that pairs of values of those two columns uniquely identify a row.  A table can only have one primary key.

In my opinion, I prefer auto-incremented numeric primary keys, with a secondary (unique composite) index for these two columns.  One reason is foreign key references, which I find easier to maintain with a single column.

Comment: Great answer! Now I understand it! Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to say that `primary key()` takes the two specified columns and uses them as a whole to create one primary key

Comment: @samyismyhero . . . You can think of it that way.  The correct terminology is a "composite primary key", meaning that the primary key is composed of multiple columns.

Comment: Found this definition for "composite key" that made things a lot clearer: `is a combination of two or more columns in a table that can be used to uniquely identify each row in the table. Uniqueness is only guaranteed when the columns are combined; when taken individually the columns do not guarantee uniqueness.`